# screen -r and screen -list only show last screen

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

My problem is pretty much as the title describes it. I am running `ssh` session and on my server I screen for multitasking. My issue here is that I have at least 4 screens open and detached, but `screen -r` connects only the the last screen I have visited. `screen -list` also only lists the last screen, as if there is only one screen open. However, once I am in one of the screens, I can freely switch between them with `Ctrl+A` and `N` and all of them are there. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen -ls` shows the sessions, and there are `windows` (also called "screens") inside the session that can be scrolled by `CTRL-A N` or listed by `CTRL-A w` or `CRTL-A "`